# Ubuntu wont boot unless

Tags: boot, grub2, asus

I'll start by saying, I am asking this question after having read most of the similar threads out there and tried what they suggest but with no luck.

So, I have this laptop https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X54H/.

I had Windows 7 installed but I erased them and I only have Ubuntu now.

When I restart my laptop and right after the Asus starting screen I get a black screen with a flashing underscore.

1. Editing grub file - Does not work.
2. Shift key pressed or spammed - Does not work.
3. Whole keyboard spammed - Works some times.

So what are your opinions? Any suggestions? Cause it's annoying to spam the whole keyboard every time, plus it's not a guaranteed solution.

Edit: Common fixes that worked for others like reinstall grub, run boot-repair, keys pressed during startup do not work in my case. I'm not an expert but I think it either is my graphics card (I don't know why but I've seen it being mentioned in other threads) or it's like the system is not booting from the right partition.
Partitions are as follow:/boot(flaged for boot), / "root", swap and /home.

Edit: Here is the report from the last repair-boot just in case....http://paste.ubuntu.com/14279575/

Comment: Can you reinstall GRUB, or repair GRUB using (well, in Live Ubuntu media) Boot-Repair?

Comment: Can you give us some more information on your laptop? Does it have the AMD graphics? Also, when you say "Windows 7 installed but I erased it", did you do a fresh install of Ubuntu, which removed everything previously from the drive? Or did you simply delete the Windows partitions from the drive after you installed Ubuntu beside Windows?

Comment: @GTrawo Yes I have AMD graphics. Yes I did a fresh ubuntu install and chose to remove windows from the disk.

Comment: @GiannisGerak Did you install the fglrx (AMD) drivers?

Comment: @GTrawo No I didn't, I am gonna do it and I`ll come back.